# Meaning of the term "Loose matrix"?

Tags: matrices, terminology

In Richard Kittredge, [*Embedded Sublanguages and Natural Language Processing*](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C80-1029), I have encountered the expression "loose matrix":

> Typically, however, causal sentences are adjoined to the right of narrow sublanguage sentences under special conjunctions in a way suggestive of a right ideal in a ring, as outlined in Harris' theoretical study. The narrow sublanguage portion of the text is distinct, both lexically and grammatically, from the rightadjoined sentences from the broader language set. A parser must be able to recognize these junctures and exploit the restrictions found in the narrow (embedded) sublanguage without failing to parse the sentences of the **loose matrix**.

I am not quite sure what he means by that (no further clarification is provided by the author). Is it the same as ["sparse matrix"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)? Could any one help me?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the text, or quote the relevant passage?

Comment: @user1551. Sure. Here you have: "Typically, however, causal sentences are adjoined to the right of narrow sublanguage sentences under special conjunctions in a way suggestive of a right ideal in a ring, as outlined in Harris' theoretical study. The narrow sublanguage portion of the text is distinct, both lexically and grammatically, from the rightadjoined sentences from the broader language set. A parser must be able to recognize these junctures and exploit the restrictions found in the narrow (embedded) sublanguage without failing to parse the sentences of the loose matrix." I hope it helps.

Comment: Interestingly, the passage mentions "a right ideal in a ring" as well, so there is a chance that "loose matrix" is really some sort of mathematical matrix. At any rate, `linguistics.stackexchange.com` is probably a more suitable place for your question. If you don't get any useful feedback here within a day or two, you may try to flag your question and ask the moderators to facilitate a migration. Or you may post the same question on `linguistics.stackexchange.com`. However, if you do so, please also delete the question here because cross-posting is discouraged.

Comment: Richard Kittredge holds degrees both in linguistics and mathematics (or computer science, I do not remember now), you of course he is making a technical use of the term. This is a mathematic question. I am a linguist, I know for sure none of my colleagues in that forum or any other could answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

*(I know almost nothing about natural language processing. So, please take this answer with a large grain of salt.)*

From p.4 of Kittredge, [*Sublanguage: Studies of Language in Restricted Semantic Domains*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jaLsYuzT3uwC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=Richard+Kittredge+%22looser+matrix%22&source=bl&ots=AJFgVsTJfC&sig=kHIpyVImrtOO2vXtahK5l6FMm4U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIjb_n76nnxwIVyiSOCh2P0wge#v=onepage&q=Richard%20Kittredge%20%22looser%20matrix%22&f=false):

> ... certain sublanguages have tightly structured "cores" which are embedded in a looser matrix whose lexical restrictions are closer to those found in the general language.

(The term is also mentioned on [p.136](https://books.google.com/books?id=jaLsYuzT3uwC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=Richard+Kittredge+%22loose+matrix%22&source=bl&ots=AJFgVsSMoG&sig=wr9vjydSzPIMTh-uUH1B1dcLyho&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMI4vPUzqfnxwIVC5GOCh1P-gV3#v=onepage&q=Richard%20Kittredge%20%22loose%20matrix%22&f=false) of the same book.)

So, apparently, "loose matrix" does mean a sparse matrix, but it seems that he is talking about the qualitative aspect of the relationship between sublanguages rather than numerical linear algebra (i.e. he is not going to solve any large sparse system of linear equations).

Comment: I am guessing that, since the relatio sublanguage-language is said to be that of right ideals in a ring, and matrices with zero entries in the last row or column being a nice example of that, he is taking the analogy to the point of saying that calculating that linguistic relation would be like calculating one of those matrices (which could eventually be sparse, but do not need to, strictly speaking): Could that be the right interpretation?

Comment: I am also not sure whether or not he would be solving equations, given that he was really responsible for some automatic-translation machine programs....I guess he was indeed feeding them with matrices and the like....

Comment: @JavierArias Sorry, I have no idea.